# Iterating through objects with numbered names

Tags: c

I'm actually trying to figured out how i can iterate through some objects in a for loop with names like "Object1, Object2, Object3..."

Here is a code to exemplify what i'm trying to do:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= numberOfObjects; i++) {
   someVariable = Object1.value/Object2.value/Object3.value; 

}
```

In this case in the part of the code that i have the Object1,Object2 and Object3 i will change for something, example Object[i].
In this case it can't be done with arrays since i don't know how much objects were created.

Comment: Are you using the C language or C++?  There is a difference and your answers will be different depending on the language.  For example, the C++ language has `std::vector`, but C doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to put the most important thing, the language.

Answer (score 2):

### For the C++ language

Put the objects into a `std::vector`.
Your loop will look like:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < object_vector.size(); ++i)
{
  result = result / object_vector[i].value;
}
```

### For the C language

```
object my_objects[] = {object1, object2, /*...*/};
array_size = sizeof(my_objects) / sizeof(object);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i)
{
  result = result / my_objects[i].value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array:

```
std::vector<T> objects{Object1, Object2, Object3};
for (auto&& x : objects) {
   someVariable = x.value; 
}
```

There's no other way to do it.